# I am Making a Random Survival Game

Tags: python

```
player_health = 100
variable_shelter = "0"
variable_water_goodoutcome = "0"
variable_water_badoutcome = "-100"
variable_food_goodoutcome = "0"
variable_food_badoutcome = "-100"
var_a = 0
var_b = 1

user_answer_1 = "fire"
user_answer_2 = "water"
user_answer_3 = "shelter"
user_answer_4 = "food"
name_input = input("Hello! Welcome to Survival Scenarios! What is your 
Name?")

question1_input = input("You are stranded on an island after your plane 
crashed.You have little time before nightfall. For your survival you 
have the choice of finding or building food, water, shelter, or fire. 
What is you choice?")

if question1_input == user_answer_1:
    import random 
    variable_fire_goodoutcome = 0
    variable_fire_badoutcome = 100
    var_choice1 = [variable_fire_goodoutcome,variable_fire_badoutcome]
    var_chances = random.randint(var_a,var_b)

if var_chances == variable_fire_goodoutcome:
    print(name_input +"'s" " Health")
    print[player_health - variable_fire_goodoutcome]

if var_chances != variable_fire_goodoutcome:
    print(name_input +"'s" " Health")
    print[player_health - variable_fire_badoutcome]
    print("Sorry you died")
```

## add information of their death later

```
if question1_input == user_answer_2:
    import random
    variable_water_goodoutcome = 0 
    variable_water_badoutcome = 100
    var_choice2 =[variable_water_goodoutcome,variable_water_badoutcome]
    var_chances1 = random.randit(var_a,var_b)

if var_chances1 == variable_water_goodoutcome:
    print(name_input +"'s"" Health")
    print[player_health - variable_water_goodoutcome]

if var_chances1 != variable_water_goodoutcome:
    print(name_input +"'s"" Health")
    print[player_health - variable_water_badoutcome]
```

keeps coming up with this error:
NameError: name 'var_chances' is not defined on line 29
If anyone could please help it would be appreciated.

Comment: var_chances will be set only if question1_input == user_answer_1:,

Comment: To Joao's point you probably want to move var_changes declaration up to the same level as var_a or var_b. I.e. default it to None or -1 or something like that :-)

Comment: Ok thanks!!! Sorry about all the repeating the website wouldn't let me post it without a lot more details.